# build failed due to "Cannot open include file: 'WinHttpClient.h': No such file or directory"

Tags: jenkins, plasticscm

I'm trying to build new product version using plastic.
I have added 4 header files to our working project compiled it locally and it works fine.
When I try to build a new solution to our product build is failing due to:
**"HandleMessage.cpp(4): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'WinHttpClient.h': No such file or directory".**
Do i need to add this files manually somewhere in plastic or something?!
I'm despaired there is no one at our company that knows the proper way to do it.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For those who encounters this problem, the solution is simple.
You probably forgot to add the files to the source control.
You go to **Items->Open Your project**, look at the files to see if they **marked as checked**. If not marked as checked, select those items and then **right click->add to source control**. After that build a new version and pray to god! :)